# Reading CI Frequency In C# With NI USB-6363

Tags: c#, labview, data-acquisition

[Working LabVIEW Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvRNv.png)

Attached above is LabVIEW code that I have successfully used in the past to read frequency data from a device. I also usually use the Start Task VI between my property node and while loop.

I am trying to code this in C#. So far I have successfully been able to code analog Output's and analog Input's on my device, USB-6363, (so I know I am able to write and read data from the device successfully with C#).

I have also used multimeters (Grainger link at bottom of post) to read frequency data (Orange Hz mode that the device is set to in the picture).

However, my C# code seems to be having issues reading the frequency data. My C# code is attached. When I try running this program I get the following error. This is the same error that I get when using the example program called 'MeasDigFreqBuffCont_ExtClk_ArmStart.2013'. The code I show is just creating the task, I do call the code later in my program in a different section and that is how I am getting the error.

------------------------------------------------- Begin Error Code -------------------------------------------------

> {Error=-200077 Message="Requested value is not a supported value for
>   this property. The property value may be invalid because it conflicts
>   with another property.\n\nProperty:
>   NationalInstruments.DAQmx.CIChannel.FrequencyDivisor\nRequested Value:
>   1\nPossible Values: 4 to 4294967295\nChannel Name: Digital
>   Frequency\n\nTask Name: _unnamedTask<0>\n\nStatus Code: -200077"}

------------------------------------------------- End Error Code --------------------------------------------------

In the example program it asks for a sample clock source (A PFI channel from the device). However in the LabVIEW code it does not ask for this. Is this example maybe more in detail than what I am trying to do?

```
Task frequencyInput = new Task();

frequencyInput.CIChannels.CreateFrequencyChannel(
                "Dev1/ctr0",
                "Digital Frequency",
                200,
                15000,
                CIFrequencyStartingEdge.Rising,
                CIFrequencyMeasurementMethod.DynamicAveraging,
                0.001,
                1,
                CIFrequencyUnits.Hertz
                );


frequencyInput.CIChannels["Digital Frequency"].FrequencyTerminal = "/Dev1/PFI0";

CounterSingleChannelReader counterFreq = new CounterSingleChannelReader(frequencyInput.Stream);


double counterFreqData = counterFreq.ReadSingleSampleDouble();

txtPFI0.Text = Convert.ToString(counterFreqData);
```

[FLUKE (R) Fluke-115 Compact - Basic Features Digital Multimeter, 14° to 122°F Temp. Range](https://www.grainger.com/product/1GAH9?gclid=CPmY0Z6FndACFYaGaQod4HAIsw&cm_mmc=PPC:GOOGLEPLAA-_-Test%20Instruments-_-Electrical%20Power%20Testing-_-1GAH9&AL!2966!3!50916686157!!!g!82166491677!&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916686157!!!g!82166491677!&ef_id=WCPN2gAAAAujkrh0:20161110013106:s)

Comment: Please paste the code from the top of the question into the question *as text*, not as an image.

Comment: Amy, The code in the top of the question is LabVIEW code, therefore there is no text based code. LabVIEW is a graphical coding language.

Comment: OK. Imgur is blocked here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting the error message:

> Requested value is not a supported value for this property. The property value may be invalid because it conflicts with another property.
>
> Property: NationalInstruments.DAQmx.CIChannel.**FrequencyDivisor** 
>   **Requested Value: 1** 
>   Possible Values: 4 to 4294967295
>
> Task Name: _unnamedTask<0>
>   Status Code: -200077

According to the [documentation](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370473H-01/mstudiowebhelp/html/eaf8d282/), you are asking the device to use an invalid *divisor*. Change your `1` to a `4`:

```c-sharp
frequencyInput.CIChannels.CreateFrequencyChannel(
                "Dev1/ctr0",
                "Digital Frequency",
                200,
                15000,
                CIFrequencyStartingEdge.Rising,
                CIFrequencyMeasurementMethod.DynamicAveraging,
                0.001,
   /* here */   4,
                CIFrequencyUnits.Hertz
                );
```

NI [installs C# examples for DAQmx](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/E3BAF6FC4017960B8625755A00525D37#net3), and it includes one for measuring frequency:

`C:\Users\Public\Documents\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\Examples\DotNET4.0\Counter\Measure Digital Frequency\MeasDigFrequency_LowFreq1Ctr\CS`

Comment: Joe,

This answered my question. So in my final code I had to change from 1 to 4 as you suggested.

I also had to change from

CIFrequencyMeasurementMethod.DynamicAveraging
TO
CIFrequencyMeasurementMethod.LowFrequencyOneCounter

This is what is shown in the example you provided. Thank you.